# Why does '%' sign impact subfigure alignment?

Tags: subfloats

These two LaTeX snippets differ only in the '%' sign at the end of subfigure 1, yet they produce different alignment of subfigures:

Snippet 1 (without '%' sign):

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_line.pdf}
        \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_region.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1b_line.pdf}
        \caption{Subfigure 3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_region.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1c_line.pdf}
        \caption{Subfigure 5}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1c_region.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 6}
    \end{subfigure}
    % \caption{Stability analysis of example \ref{example:compound}}
    \caption{Hello}
\end{figure*}
```

Snippet 1 (with '%' sign):

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_line.pdf}
        \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_region.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1b_line.pdf}
        \caption{Subfigure 3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_region.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1c_line.pdf}
        \caption{Subfigure 5}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1c_region.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 6}
    \end{subfigure}
    % \caption{Stability analysis of example \ref{example:compound}}
    \caption{Hello}
\end{figure*}
```

Why does the '%' sign influence subfigure placement?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Although your question is clear (because this is a well-known part of TeX), the code you've given us isn't really helpful: we don't have your images, and you've posted a fragment of code rather than a compilable document. For future questions it's best to post a complete document that others can compile that shows your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Some general comments:

- The 7 `\centering` instructions per `figure*` environment don't do anything useful; delete them.
- The OP's first `figure*` environment shows only two, rather than three, subfigures per row. That is because the implicit whitespace after each `\end{subfigure}` is allowed to persist.
  That's not the case in the OP's second `figure*` environment.

Anyway, I think what your float really needs is a handful of well-placed `\hfill` directives per row, along with a very slight reduction in relative subfigure width, from `0.33\textwidth` to `0.32\textwith`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.25\baselineskip}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_line.pdf}
      \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_region.png}
      \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1b_line.pdf}
      \caption{Subfigure 3}
    \end{subfigure} % keep the next line blank to force a line-break
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1a_region.png}
      \caption{Subfigure 4}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1c_line.pdf}
      \caption{Subfigure 5}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1c_region.png}
      \caption{Subfigure 6}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Stability analysis}
    \label{example:compound}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\floatsep
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 5}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{Subfigure 6}
    \end{subfigure}
    % \caption{Stability analysis of example \ref{example:compound}}
    \caption{Hello}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You wrote, "It seems like having `\textwidth` inside each subfigure's width is the issue." That's not the case.